# Find resource in separate folder to class file

Tags: java, file, filepath

I'm trying to find a txt file in a separate folder to the class

### Class file

```
C://workspace/project/src/pkg/Class.java
```

### txt file

```
C://workspace/project/doc/pkg/myFile.txt
```

I'm trying to find the text file without having to hard code the `C://workspace/project/` bit

Is this possible?

Currently I can use a `classpath:/pkg/myFile.txt` when the file is in the same package as `Class.java` using a resource loader

Comment: Since when Windows started to use / as a path separator?

Comment: Do you *actually* have a class by the name of `Class.java`?

Comment: @Chiron  It is not best practices, but will work.

Comment: Are these resources supplied by you or the user?  If by you, access them as an [tag:embedded-resource] by `URL`.  If the user, offer them a [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Comment: You can load a resource relative `this.getResourceAsStream("../../doc/pkg/myFile.txt")`

Answer (score 1):

You could inclide the doc folder as a source folder. That way you can keep your resources separate from the code, but still have access to it using a classloader.

Of course that will only work for you when your resource can be part of the jar. If not, you may want to consider using a properties where you can configure the complete path to the resource.

Comment: i would like to keep them as an ordinary folder (so not a source folder). does that mean that a properties is the only way, i was trying to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

Try getClass().getResource() or getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() if it is in the same jar-file